# .Jar File Compatibility

Tags: java, windows, macos, jar

If I compile java source files into a .jar file on a mac, will that same .jar program run on a windows machine? Thanks for your help, sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: yes,, compile once run anywhere motto of Java :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the whole point of Write Once Run Anywhere :-)

A minor point: You compile Java source code into bytecode (class files). The JAR file merely packages the bytecode (and does some other nifty things like digital signatures, compression, etc.)